# How to make the cursor always jump to point-max for Emacs gdb?

Tags: debugging, emacs, gdb, elisp

When debugging in Emacs with gdb-mi, the cursor in `*gud-xxx*` window always fails to jump to `point-max`, then I follow some other's settings and make some `advice` like below:

```
(defun hack-gud-mode ()
  (when (string= major-mode "gud-mode")
    (goto-char (point-max))))

(defadvice switch-to-buffer (after switch-to-buffer-after activate)
  (hack-gud-mode))

(defadvice comint-send-input (after comint-send-input-after activate)
  (hack-gud-mode))

(defadvice windmove-do-window-select (after windmove-do-window-select-after activate)
  (hack-gud-mode))


(defadvice gud-call (after gud-call-select-after activate)
  (hack-gud-mode))
```

But the problem still exists: when I hit some gdb command and press <kbd>Ret</kbd>(**comint-send-input**), there is still no guarantee that the cursor would jump. Also I feel that it is too frustrating to add so many advice functions. Is there any better setting for it?

Comment: What's the value of your `comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-input` and `comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-output` variables?  Perhaps experimentation w/these will help.

Comment: @assem Both of them are nil. I will try, thanks.

Comment: @assem It works at least for the command I am using now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Strictly for the sake of completion, I'm writing here what @assem proposed in the comments.)*

`comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-input` scrolls the comint buffer whenever you enter stuff.
`comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-output` scrolls the buffer along with the output (this is probably the most relevant one).

You should set them both to `t` using:

```
(setq comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-input t)
(setq comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-output t)
```

You may also want to set `comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-output` to `'others` instead of `t`. This way it will only scroll if the buffer is not currently focused.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be 100% sure (since my gdb works fine), but I would experiment by changing your hack-gud-mode by adding something like

```
(run-with-timer 0.25 nil (lambda () (goto-char (point-max))))
```

Since there is a small delay between emacs sending stuff to underlying process and emacs getting the response.  Only the `comint-send-input` would need to be adviced, if this works

(however, I wonder about the root cause of your problem)

Comment: Maybe there should be a `nil` after 0.25? I don't know why the cursor doesn't jump wisely, even I haven't configured anything for it, or `comint`.